# Date filtering between Mondays

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using GAS, I'd like to filter a column of dates between the most recent Monday and the Monday before that. Below is some code I've tried to implement but it doesn't work.
`

```
function filt() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
let filter = ss.getFilter();
let criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                             .whenFormulaSatisfied("=ISBETWEEN(F2:F,(TODAY()-7 - WEEKDAY(TODAY()-7,3)),(TODAY()-14 - WEEKDAY(TODAY()-14,3))")
                             .build();
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(6, criteria);
}
```

`

This code just gives me a blank spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using will error out because `today() - 7` is not before `today() - 14` but after it. You can fix it like this:

`=isbetween(F2:F, today() - weekday(today(), 3) - 14, today() - weekday(today(), 3) - 7)`